# Handling Privileges of Users that are Not Authorized

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

let's say i have two privileges : Admin and Host and i have a default page.

after logging in : admin users can see everything but host users can't see few buttons in the page

so am i supposed to duplicate the default page? or is there a way to disable the buttons on redirection to the default page?

```
  If Login1.Password = Session("pwd") Then
        Response.Redirect("profile_test_1.aspx")
    End If
```

note that I'm using web applications

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I work with C#, but I'm pretty sure this would fit VB aswell.
You can use the `LoginView` webcontrol, and of course, keep everything in the same page.

**Example**

```
<asp:LoginView ID="LoginView1" Runat="server">
  <LoggedInTemplate>
   <asp:LoginName ID="LoginName1" Runat="server" 
                  FormatString ="Welcome, {0}"/>
   <br />
    <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" Runat="server" 
      NavigateUrl="~/MemberPages/ChangePassword.aspx">
      Change Password
    </asp:HyperLink>
  </LoggedInTemplate>
  <AnonymousTemplate>
    <asp:Login id="Login1" runat="server" 
        CreateUserText="Create a new user..."
        CreateUserUrl="~/Register.aspx" 
        PasswordRecoveryUrl="~/Recovery.aspx" 
        UserNameLabelText="E-mail address:" />
  </AnonymousTemplate>
</asp:LoginView>
```

In this example I'm separating blocks for logged in and anonymous users, but you can do the same based on `Roles`.

Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178329%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You could create a sub that will run after the user is validated. You could pass a boolean Admin and the sub will hide/show the required buttons. You could call this on postback or page_load depending on how you pass the users role.

Pseudocode:

```
Sub SetPermissions(Byval blAdmin as boolean)

    If blAdmin Then
        'Insert code to showbuttons; ie. btnAdminOnly.Visible = True
    Else
        'Insert code to hide buttons; ie. btnAdminOnly.Visible = False
    End If

End Sub
```